# Are borel sets topologies?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I was reading about borel sets in big Rudin and something I noticed was that borel sets of a measurable space contain all open sets of the space. So my question is, are borel sets topologies or did I misread something.

Comment: Do you mean, is the collection of all Borel sets a topology?

Comment: Is each borel set a topology

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Borel sets are generated by a topology. This doesn't give a topology in the case of $\Bbb{R}$. Every singleton set is Borel and topologies are closed under arbitrary unions but not every set is Borel.

Comment: Footnote: So in the case of $\Bbb R$, because every singleton is Borel, if the Borel sets were a topology then it would be the discrete topology. However, not every subset of $\Bbb R$ is Borel.

Comment: This is absolutely right, but technically we need to *prove* that there is a non-Borel set of reals, and this is harder than it seems - in fact, for the usual definition of "Borel," it's not provable in ZF alone! It is consistent with ZF that the reals are a countable union of countable sets - in such a model, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets is the whole powerset of $\mathbb{R}$. In ZFC, though, the proof is easy: there are continuum-many Borel sets, but $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$-many sets of reals total.